# Open Multiple Windows of a non-Stackable Program?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Some programs allow only up to 1 instance running at a time. Is there any way to circumvent this limit and get multiple, completely separate instances of that program (without a virtual machine)?

Specifically, I want to know if you can do this with NCH Software's VideoPad, as I only allows 1 instance and 1 parent window.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean *some programs only allow one instance of program to run*? Or do you really mean "window"? In any case, please give an example or two of such a program.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "instance" and "window"?

Comment: A window is an individual, well, *window* that typically has a title bar and its own Close, Minimize, and Maximize buttons. Many programs can have multiple windows. Conversely, when one starts a program, they're creating a single *instance* of that program which can of course have multiple windows. Taking a word processing program as an example, if you already have an instance of it running and open another document, you'll just get another window within that instance. However, if you intentionally run the program's executable a second time...

Comment: ...and it supports being run in multiple instances, you'll end up with a second instance of a program, with its own set of windows. The Windows OS stacks the windows of a program's *instance* together, but not separate instances of the same program.

Comment: Thanks for the detail, but you didn't need to be THAT specific. I guess what I would be asking for how to get multiple instances. For example, one of my programs allows only 1 instance and 1 main/parent window. If you try to load a new *instance* of the program up, it just puts the already existing window of the program on top.

Comment: LOL. I didn't want to assume what you did or did not know. Please edit your question to use the term "instance" and indicate what program you're trying to do this with.

Comment: Fixed the Question :P

Comment: One way is to run the program as another user.

Comment: True, but that wouldn't be practical in my situation as it would take too much time (I need to be able to switch back and forth quickly or just kind of be able to run both instances simultaneously.

Comment: I don't mean by logging out of the computer. I think you can Shift+ Right-click a program to get the **Ran as different user** option.